# Does this Cauchy problem $x'=tx^{2/3}$, $x(0)=0$ have unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

Consider the following Cauchy problem:
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
 x'=tx^{2/3} \\
 \\ x(0)=0 \\
 \end{array}
\right.
$$
I proceed as usual. First we notice that $x(t)=0 \ \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant solution of the separable equation. If we suppose that $x\neq 0$ we get that
$$
x^{-2/3}x'=t
$$
And integrating with respect to $t$ we get:
$$
3x^{1/3}=\frac{t^2}{2}+C_1 \\
x(t)=\left(\frac{t^2}{6}+C_2\right)^3
$$
with $C$ constant.
Here is my doubt: in the definition of solution that was given to me we have to specify an open interval $I$ where $x(t)$ is defined. As I want to solve the Cauchy problem, $0$ must be in $I$. However, in that case $x$ would be zero and to obtain the second solution I imposed that $x\neq 0$. How many solutions does this problem have? I would say only one, the constant solution, but I'm not sure if I should include the second one (to get the constant $C_2$ just substitute and we get that $C_2=0$)

Comment: Why not include the second solution *you* found (the one with $C_2=0$)?

Comment: But this answers your question better: [Existence and uniqueness of soluctions of $y'=xy^{2/3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036943/existence-and-uniqueness-of-soluctions-of-y-xy2-3), showing that actually, there are many more solutions.